# Open datasets for affiliation networks between African farmers?

Tags: data-request, food, network-structure, africa

I'm looking for any other datasets and open access pubs on affiliation/bipartite networks using survey data from farmers/community members in rural Africa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UN Food & Agriculture Organization (FAO) collects and publishes a lot of data on Africa related to farming.

Here's the entry point into the FAO's Statistics Database (FAOSTAT):

http://faostat.fao.org/

Here's the link to the World Bank's datasets on Farming in Rural Areas of the World:

http://data.worldbank.org/topic/agriculture-and-rural-development

The CGIAR/CCAFS program at Harvard University collects and publishes data surveys related to Agriculture in Africa:

https://thedata.harvard.edu/dvn/dv/CCAFSbaseline

Here's an example of where Columbia University has used the FAO data:

http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/maproom/Agriculture/Farming_Systems/Africa/

Here's an example of where Australian Centre for International Agricultural Research has used FAO data on farming in Africa

http://aciar.gov.au/files/node/14087/mapping_farming_systems_in_africa_21_june_2012_16871.ppt

Here's a dataset from 2012 covering 35 million hectacres of farm land in 66 countries that has been bought up by foreign firms:

http://www.grain.org/article/entries/4479-grain-releases-data-set-with-over-400-global-land-grabs

**FOR AFFILATIONS:**
NATIONAL AFRICAN FARMERS’ UNION (NAFU)
African Farmers Association of South Africa (AFASA) - http://www.afasa.za.org/
East Africa Farmer's Federation - http://eaffu.org/eaffu/

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to keep an eye on the independent think tanks & research organisations that post their data on [openAFRICA.net](http://openAFRICA.net).

The International Livestock Research Institute (ILRI), for example, maintains ~115 Africa-specific datasets on the portal. Here's the link: http://africaopendata.org/organization/ilri

Answer (score 0):

Also recommend checking [USAID's Development Data Library (DDL)](http://www.usaid.gov/data), where datasets on developing countries are added on a regular basis.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Could you please disclose your affiliation with USAID and explain in a few words how the Development Data Library can be used with regard to the original poster's question?

Comment: I'm the Chief Data Officer @ USAID. Datasets continuously added to the DDL.

Comment: Thanks! If you could update your answer accordingly, that would be perfect :)

Comment: Will do. Org affiliation already in my profile.